# Let $p: X \to Y$ be a perfect map. Show that if $X$ is regular, $Y$ is regular.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, separation-axioms

I'm stuck here:

> Let $p: X \rightarrow Y$ be a perfect map (closed, surjective and continuous map) such that $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact for each $y \in Y$.
>
> Show that  if $X$ is regular, then $Y$ is regular.

I've been struggling for several hours , but I always get nothing.

**EDIT: My try.** Take a $y\in Y$ and a closed space $C$ in $Y$, such that $y$ is not in $C$. I want to show that I can put $y$ and $C$ in open disjoint sets of $Y$. I consider $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ and $p^{-1}(C)$. $p^{-1}(\{y\})$ is compact, and $p^{-1}(C)$ is closed.

Comment: How did you begin your proof? Or, more importantly, how will your proof end?

Comment: @DavidSnyder Edited. Thanks!

Comment: $f;X \rightarrow Y$ is closed iff for every $y \in Y$ and every open neighbourhood $U$ of $f^{-1}[\{y\}]$ in $X$ there exists some open neighbourhood $V$ of $y$ in $Y$ such that $f^{-1}[V] \subseteq U$. This is not too hard to prove. It shows closedness of $f$ to be a sort of "inverse fibre continuity". Then use that compact subsets of regular spaces behave "like points", in the sense that disjoint compact and closed sets have disjoint neighbourhoods. Combining these makes the result immediate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $y\in Y$ and $C$ be closed in $Y$ such that $y\notin C$.

Since $p$ is surjective so $p^{-1}(y)\neq\emptyset$. Since $p$ is continuous then $p^{-1}(C)$ is closed in $X$.

Also $p^{-1}(y)\cap p^{-1}(C)=\emptyset $.

Hence since $X$ is regular for each $z\in p^{-1}(y)$ we find disjoint open sets $U_z $ and $V_z$ such that $z\in U_z,p^{-1}(C)\subset V_z$ .

Then $\cup_{z\in p^{-1}(y)}\{U_z\}$ is an open cover of $p^{-1}(y)$ which is compact and hence there exists $z_1,z_2,\ldots z_n$ such that $U=\cup_{i=1}^n U_i=p^{-1}(y)$. Take those $z_1,z_2,\ldots z_n$ and consider $V_{z_1},V_{z_2},\ldots V_{z_n}$.

Consider $V=\cap_{i=1}^n V_{z_i}$

Then $p^{-1}(y)\subset U\implies y\in p(U)$ and $p^{-1}(C)\subset V\implies C\subset p(V)$ and $U\cap V=\emptyset$

**EDIT**:
How do we obtain the open sets $W_1,W_2$ in $Y$ which separates $\{y\}$ and $C$?

> Since $p^{-1}(y)\subset U$ so there exists an open set $W_1$ containing $y$ such that $p^{-1}(W_1)\subset U$,where we take $W_1=Y\setminus  p(X\setminus U)$.
>
> Similarly we obtain an open set $W_2$ containing $C$ such that $p^{-1}(W_2)\subset V$,where we take $W_2=Y\setminus  p(X\setminus V)$.
>
> Also $W_1\cap W_2 \subset U\cap V=\emptyset$

Comment: Why $p^{-1}(y)\cap p^{-1}(C)=\emptyset $?

Comment: $z\in p^{-1}(y)\cap p^{-1}(C)\implies p(z)=y;p(z)\in C\implies y\in C$

Comment: Also, $p$ is a closed map, not an open map so $p(U), p(V)$ aren't necessarily open.

Comment: The missing detail.

Comment: Thanks @David and OP. I see it now.

Comment: So essentially your argument (in the comment above) proves that if $p:X\to Y$ be a closed surjective map then it is also an open surjective map. Am I right?

Comment: you need to show that $p(U)\cap p(V)=\varnothing$. this is not clear

Comment: @ForeverMozart: I think that using the above argument as is shown, one can show also that if $p:X\to Y$ is an open surjective map then it is also a closed map (which is not true in general).

Comment: The reason is, $$U\ \text{closed}\implies X\setminus U\ \text{open} \implies \underbrace{p(X\setminus U)\ \text{open}}_{\text{since}\ p\ \text{is an open map}}\implies \underbrace{Y\setminus p(U)\ \text{open}}_{\text{since}\ p\ \text{is surjective}}$$

Comment: I don't remember it very well but I think that $p(X\setminus U)=Y\setminus p(U)$ if $p$ is bijective. Only surjection willn't be enough as I have shown above.

Comment: but an open map need not map disjoint open sets to disjoint sets...

Comment: @ForeverMozart;See my edits ;Hopefully it will clear your doubts

Comment: @user170039;See the edits